# onContextItemSelected fragment instance issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity contains two fragments, instanciated with the same class.

Using the contextual menu, when I select a menu action from the second fragment/listview, logging the instance members shows that onContextItemSelected is called from the first fragment instance only:

```
public class LikedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMyInstanceId = getArguments().getString("fragmentId"); // "first" or "second"
    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mActivity, MyQueries.getMyCursor(mMyInstanceId));

        AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_liked, menu);
        Log.d(TAG, mMyInstanceId); // OKAY: logs "second" 
    }

    @Override public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, mMyInstanceId); // FAIL: logs "first"
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

How can I get the right instance in onContextItemSelected ?

Comment: What is mMyInstanceId?

Comment: a string passed as bundle argument to differentiate the two fragment instances, I'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

Just use group id to fix this. Just assign different group id to both fragment & then check them in onContextItemSelected like following.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
menu.add(GROUP_ID, MENU_1, 0, "Menu 1");
menu.add(GROUP_ID, MENU_2, 0, "Menu 2");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
//only this fragment's context menus have group ID of -1
if (item.getGroupId() == GROUP_ID) 
{
    //Your Code Will Be Added Here
}
```